# POST in MEAN app send null

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, express, mean

I am writing a CRUD app using MEAN stack and when I try to POST an object to add it to a collection in the mongo database it adds objects that have only "id", "update_date" and "_v".

It works fine and adds proper objects when I just open a simple HTML file with a form of method="post", but when I try to use this inside the angular app it just sends the objects without the make, year and model properties.

This is my add-car.component.html:

```
<div>
  <h1>Add car</h1>

  <form (ngSubmit)="addCar()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="make">Make</label>
      <input type="text" name="make" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="car.make">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="model">Model</label>
      <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="car.model">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="year">Year</label>
      <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="car.year">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

This is the add-car.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-car',
  templateUrl: './add-car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-car.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AddCarComponent implements OnInit {

  car = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,  private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addCar() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/cars', this.car).subscribe(
      res => {
        //this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

}

Here's the part of code defining the mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: String,
    model: String,
    year: String,
    updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema, 'cars');
```

I have no idea why this isn't working, it's probably something stupid I'm not seeing.

Comment: check your network tab

Comment: Have you added the `FormsModule` to your module imports?

Comment: Yes, the `FormsModule` is added to the imports in app.module.ts.

@Sajeetharan could you elaborate? I don't know what the network tab is

Comment: if you are using chrome, open developer tools and check network tab what is the request

Comment: I copied your code and it seems to work fine. Have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuoppt. If you check the browser's console, the response is logged out. Maybe your server running on port 3001 is not running properly?

Comment: It's weird but when I `console.log()` the object in the backend server it shows an empty object. But when I try it with a simple html file with a post form it works fine...

Comment: What's your backend made of? an expressjs app? You need to add an express middleware to extract the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the backend server which didn't have this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

So it couldn't parse the object that was sent as a json file.

Comment: Could have let me post the answer since I found it, but glad I could help anyway